How to view embedded images on a KMZ with QGIS
I use this app called Avenza to note areas of interest during site visits for my job. At each point that you mark you can attach images taken at that area. The free version of the app only lets me export the file as a KMZ which is fine when viewing on Google Earth. (i.e. I can just click the point and the images show up in a pop-up).
The issue is when I import the KMZ to QGIS. The points show up, the path shows up, the name of the points can be toggled, but I can't figure out how to get the images associated with each point to show up.
How could I get the images to show up when I click each point whether in a separate up or in a local pop up. At the bare minimum I'd like to at least now the file filename of the image so I can reference the image.

unzip the kmz > there should be a doc.kml and images folder with your image if embedded - if network linked it maybe harder to extact.

The outputted kmz is zipped though, just a regular file. Is there a way to unzip it?

7-Zip (Freeware) will extract the contents of a KMZ.  https://www.7-zip.org/

or rename xxx.kmz to xxx.zip and unzip in windows.

It's not an issue of the getting to the images. The images are automatically saved to my camera roll and I upload them in a separate folder. The issue is that they are not accessible through QGIS.
